# Changing List View contents when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am trying to show all sms messages from Inbox in a list view.

**Problem:**

Messages are populated properly in List View when I launch the Activity. But when I scroll it up or down the contents of **some** messages in **middle** and **corner** positions are changed automatically. I'm unable to trace the reason for this abnormal behavior of list. Can you please see what is the issue with the adapter class or other part of code.

**Code:**

I'm using following custom adapter to fill a ListView.

```
import java.util.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private String FIRST_COLUMN = "First";
    private String SECOND_COLUMN = "Second";
    private String THIRD_COLUMN = "Third";
    private String FOURTH_COLUMN = "Fourth";
    private String FIFTH_COLUMN = "Fifth";
    private String SIXTH_COLUMN = "Sixth";
    String class_name="";

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
    TextView txtFourth;
    TextView txtFifth;
    TextView txtSixth;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,
                           ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
        class_name = activity.getClass().toString();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {  
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_row, null);
                txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMsgId_msg);
                txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCtId_msg);
                txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCtName_msg);
                txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCtNo_msg);
                txtFifth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMsgDate_msg);
                txtSixth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSms_msg);
        }

        HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
        txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
        txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));
    txtFifth.setText(map.get(FIFTH_COLUMN));
        txtSixth.setText(map.get(SIXTH_COLUMN));

        return convertView;
    }

    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

And, here is the part of code that populates the list.

```
private void showInboxMessages() {
        String SORT_ORDER = "date DESC";
        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, null, null, null, SORT_ORDER);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToLast();
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {    
                HashMap<String, String> contacts = new HashMap<String, String>();
                int _id = 1;
                do {
                    //String _id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                    String person = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("person"));
                    String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));

                    if (person == null || person.equals("")) {
                        if (contacts.containsKey(address))
                            person = (String) contacts.get(address);
                        else {
                            person = Methods.getContactName(this, address);
                            contacts.put(address,person);
                        }
                    } 
                    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
                    Long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));
                    Date dateVal=new Date(date);
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT2, Locale.getDefault());
                    String datetext = dateFormat.format(dateVal);
                    add_to_list(String.valueOf(_id), "", person, address, datetext, body);
                    _id ++;
                } while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
            }
        }
    }


private void add_to_list(String i, String n, String c, String d, String e, String f) {
        HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
        temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, i);
        temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, n);
        temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, c);
        temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, d);
        temp.put(FIFTH_COLUMN, e);
        temp.put(SIXTH_COLUMN, f);
        listarray.add(temp);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically listview recycles your views. You need to check concept of viewholders. 
For example :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_entry, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
        holder.surnameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_surname);
        holder.personImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.person_image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Person person = getItem(position);

    holder.nameTextView.setText(person.getName());
    holder.surnameTextView.setText(person.getSurname());
    //holder.personImageView.setImageBitmap(person.getImage());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by removing `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`from add_to_list method and ADD this line inside `if (cursor.getCount() > 0)` But after/outside do While loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Copy and paste code below then see if there is change. This must be work for now. Hope this help. Setting final to all view/position to not change the value.


import java.util.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private String FIRST_COLUMN = "First";
private String SECOND_COLUMN = "Second";
private String THIRD_COLUMN = "Third";
private String FOURTH_COLUMN = "Fourth";
private String FIFTH_COLUMN = "Fifth";
private String SIXTH_COLUMN = "Sixth";
String class_name="";

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;
TextView txtFirst;
TextView txtSecond;
TextView txtThird;
TextView txtFourth;
TextView txtFifth;
TextView txtSixth;

public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,
                       ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
    class_name = activity.getClass().toString();

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {  
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_row, null);
            txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMsgId_msg);
            txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCtId_msg);
            txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCtName_msg);
            txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCtNo_msg);
            txtFifth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMsgDate_msg);
            txtSixth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSms_msg);
    }

    HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
    txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));
txtFifth.setText(map.get(FIFTH_COLUMN));
    txtSixth.setText(map.get(SIXTH_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
}

public void clear() {
    list.clear();
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed code of the adapter class and used ArrayList with my data model class 'Message'. Now list is showing and scrolling properly.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
    private ArrayList<Message> dataItems;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> items) {
        super(context, R.layout.messages_row, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.dataItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messages_row, parent, false);

        TextView _id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMsgId_msg);
        TextView ctId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCtId_msg);
        TextView ctName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCtName_msg);
        TextView ctNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCtNo_msg);
        TextView msgDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMsgDate_msg);
        TextView msg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSms_msg);

        Message obj = (Message) dataItems.get(position);

        _id.setText(String.valueOf(obj.get_id()));
        ctId.setText(String.valueOf(obj.getContact_id()));
        ctName.setText(String.valueOf(obj.getContact_Name()));
        ctNo.setText(String.valueOf(obj.getContact_No()));
        msgDate.setText(String.valueOf(obj.getSms_date()));
        msg.setText(String.valueOf(obj.getSms()));


        return convertView;
    }
}
```